# Past Simple or Past Perfect in context of a story

Tags: past-tense, perfect-constructions

we were creating a story and stumbled over this sentence:

> I remembered the day when she had come up with an idea...

So in this sentence is it better to use Past Perfect or is it better to say "I remembered the day when she **came** up with an idea..." - since we're remembering a specific day in the past? But on the other hand, the first verb was remembered, and the thing he's remembering happened before that moment of remembering? Could you share your vision of this question?

Comment: Hi. Tense choice is often very dependent on the context or sequence of events in a story. It's really hard to tell you what to use based on a single sentence.  It would be better if you could share a paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for responding). our story went like this - At the age of 25  a man called Jack opened a backery.  He had grown up with his grandma who he had been looking after  until she died.  He remembered the day she had come up with an idea of a special recipe for pastries to cheer him up. And when he met a girl he liked and wanted to impres this resipe was an inspiration for him...

Comment: It's bakery not backery. The rest looks fine to me.  Note however that proof reading is off-topic here.

Comment: This is the correct use of past perfect, following a simple past. That said, it depends on the temporal emphasis you want to give the sentence.

Comment: If you REALLY want to stress that she came up with the idea before you remembered: FINE. If not, don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need* the Perfect form in the cited context - so as ever, it's best *not* to use it. There's just one single instance of the Perfect being used in this exact sequence in Google Books...

> *She* [*remembered the day when she **had come***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22remembered%20the%20day%20when%20she%20had%20come%22&tbm=bks&ei=A4auZK3jKoOR8gKBxbLwDw&ved=0ahUKEwjt8JejgImAAxWDiFwKHYGiDP4Q4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22remembered%20the%20day%20when%20she%20had%20come%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQlIIFWJSCBWCChgVoAHAAeACAAUmIAfcBkgEBNJgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books) *here with her brother*

...compared to about a dozen instances of...

> *He* [*remembered the day when she **came...***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22remembered%20the%20day%20when%20she%20came%22&tbm=bks&ei=HIauZOHYDImPhbIP5v2o-AU&ved=0ahUKEwjh1u-ugImAAxWJR0EAHeY-Cl8Q4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22remembered%20the%20day%20when%20she%20came%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQ7xFY7xFgmBhoAXAAeACAAdwBiAGpApIBBTEuMC4xmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books)

It's not *wrong* to use Past Perfect in such contexts, but obviously most published writers *don't*.

Comment: I disagree completely. And Google Books ain't the god of English. We all are.

Comment: You're perfectly entitled to disagree with the *implication* of my answer (that the OP *shouldn't* use the Perfect form in his specific example). I don't really see how you can *justify* advising a learner to use verb forms that apparently less than 1 in 10 *published writers* choose to use. But as my answer points out, it's not *wrong* to do so. Just *in my opinion* not a very good idea.

Comment: I don't go by published writers. I go by my own internalized uses of grammar.

Comment: Do you not agree with my oft-repeated observation that most learners tend to overuse Perfect verb forms?

Comment: Yes, but that does not make it wrong. Also, I use it quite a bit; it just isn't vestigial yet.

Comment: But I'm not even claiming it's "wrong" even in this specific context! Just that (and this is advice specifically and *only* aimed at nns) it would generally be better not to use a Perfect verb form if you don't *need* to. And unquestionably in the cited context, you *don't* need to use it. But I wouldn't even have an opinion as regards whether a *native* Anglophone chooses to use an (optional) Perfect form - each of us *as a native speaker* has their own "internal grammarian", and I've never much sided with pedantic / prescriptive teachers telling the natives how they should talk and write.